# set -x equivalent for the Postgres cli/console/prompt/repl

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is there a "set -x" for the Postgres prompt/repl ?

In bash when you want to execute a set of commands, and come back to check it after lunch you can do

```
set -x
command1
command2
command3
```

and bash prints out the command to STDOUT just before it executes it.
this is helpful to see, what's taking a long time, which did line did it last execute, etc.

Similarly, inside the psql console, I also do sets of long running commands:

```
VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE events;
REINDEX VERBOSE TABLE events;
```

Can I do

```
set -x
VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE events;
REINDEX VERBOSE TABLE events;
```

so that when I come back from lunch I can see which one of **my commands** was the last one it did.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want `\set ECHO queries`.